# Extended TableViewCell blank

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to customize a UITableViewCell, but for some reason it's showing up as blank. Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong? I've pulled the menuLabel from the storyboard as an outlet, so it's tied correctly, and the cell in the storyboard is linked to the class "MenuCell".

In my tableview controller

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MenuCell";
[self.tableView registerClass:[MenuCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
MenuCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if(cell == nil) {
    NSLog(@"creating a new cell");
    cell = [[MenuCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                              reuseIdentifier:@"MenuCell"];
}

cell.menuLabel.text = @"Hello";


return cell;
}
```

Comment: why does adding 'cell = (MenuCell *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MenuCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];' work?

Comment: because you have to load nib for your custom cell.

Comment: but everything i have is in storyboard, no nib file?

Comment: Sorry i didn't work with storyboard, my idea was for nib file.

Comment: its still failing to load the correct cell then...with storyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MenuCell";

            MenuCell *cell = (MenuCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                UINib* customCellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MenuCell" bundle:nil];

                // Register this nib file with cell identifier.

                [tableView registerNib: customCellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                cell = (MenuCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            }
    // Whatever you want 
retrun cell;
    }
```

Hope this will help. happy coding :P

Answer (score 1):

Use this one ....

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MenuCell";
        MenuCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[MenuCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            cell = (MenuCell *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MenuCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

        }
        cell.menuLabel.text = @"Hello";
        return cell;
    }
```

I Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: why did this work? strange I have the same code in another tablewviewcontroller htat's exactly the same as in the problem, but it works.

Comment: this works, but I can't customize cell appearance in MenuCell loader

Comment: what i coundn't follow u ?